# Python regex finding all multi line occurences in file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file including tons of output like this:

```
<Tons-of-random-text>
...
Received Access-Accept (code=2) length=300
  Attribute 2 (User-Name) length=16
    Value 'myTextValue1'
  Attribute 4 (Bla1) length=16
    Value 'myTextValue2'
  Attribute 6 (Bla2) length=16
    Value 0xABCDEFG
<Tons-of-random-text>
```

At the end of the day I want to use named capture groups to extract:

- the `code` in the first outlined line.
- A list of Attributes

Based on the example above, the desired extract data structe is:

```py
code=2
attributes = [
    {
        "attribute": "2",
        "attribute-name": "User-Name",
        "value": "myTextValue1"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "4",
        "attribute-name": "Bla1",
        "value": "myTextValue2"
    },
    # ...
]
```

I'm struggling with `finditer` and `findall`... at the end of the day I'm only able to match the first or the last attribute block...
Anybody have a hint for a good regex?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This code will match the line with `(code=\d)` and what follows for as long as each lines contains "Attribute" or "Value".

```
/(\(code=\d\).*$(\n^\s*(Attribute|Value).*$)+)/gm
```

see https://regex101.com/r/HzIW5V/1